# Adding object to NSMutableArray, trying to reloadData on UITableView, new object not showing. :(

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have successfully set up a `UITableView` that pulls its cell labels from an array. What I am trying to do is *add an object to that array and reload the UITableView* so it'll show that new object and create a new cell. Unfortunately, I have no luck.

I know it is probably something very stupid that I did in the code, but can someone let me know where I went wrong? Here is what I am currently using:

**here is my whole .h:**

```
@interface crastinatrViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {

NSMutableArray *tasksList;

UIView *addtaskview;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *mainTableView;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *tasksList;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *taskName;

- (IBAction)addTask:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)startaddTask:(id)sender;
@end
```

**and my whole .m:**

```
@interface crastinatrViewController ()

@end

@implementation crastinatrViewController

@synthesize mainTableView;

@synthesize tasksList;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    tasksList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];
    self.mainTableView.delegate = self;
    self.mainTableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.taskName becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSInteger rows = [[self tasksList] count];

    NSLog(@"rows is: %d", rows);
    return rows;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *contentForThisRow = [[self tasksList] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        // Do anything that should be the same on EACH cell here.  Fonts, colors, etc.
    }

    // Do anything that COULD be different on each cell here.  Text, images, etc.
    [[cell textLabel] setText:contentForThisRow];

    return cell;}

-(IBAction)startaddTask:(id)sender {

    addtaskview = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addTaskView"];

    [self presentViewController:addtaskview animated:YES completion:nil];


}

- (IBAction)addTask:(id)sender {

    [tasksList addObject:self.taskName.text];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    [mainTableView reloadData];
}

@end
```

Comment: Log and check the array count, you can know weather the object is added or not.

Comment: Which view you are dismissing dismissViewControllerAnimated ? And where is taskList and mainTableView is declared ?

Comment: in which class mainTableView ??

Comment: Have you got `tasksList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` anywhere in your code?

Comment: Share the code for tableview implementation, including the DataSource and Delegate. Without that, it wil be difficult to help.

Comment: @Roshit I have just edited my post and added all my code, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you have done initialization of the taskList array. 
Like 'tasksList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]'.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [mainTableView reloadData];
}];
```

Also, put breakpoints and check if on call of `reloadData`, the TableView Delegate and DataSource methods are called.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are hardcoded numberOfRowsInSection please check, it will be -

```
              - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
                     return [tasksList count];
                 }
```